# Choose default webcam for node-webkit

Tags: google-chrome, node-webkit

I have a node-webkit application that is using RecordRTC to capture a snippet of video. I'm running the application on a Windows Surface Pro 3, and need the front-facing webcam to be used instead of the back-facing one. I know there is a setting in Chrome to change the default webcam, but how do I configure this in node-webkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a device to test this on but it should work. I believe mobile devices will return either 'user' or 'environment' to determine if it's front or rear facing.

```js
var devices = function (devices) {
  for (var i = 0; i !== devices.length; ++i) {
    var camera = devices[i];
    if (camera.kind === 'video' && camera.facing === 'user') {
       createStream(camera.id);
    } else {
      console.log('No front facing camera');
    } 
  }
}

var createStream = function(id) {
  var settings = {video: {optional: {sourceId: id} }};
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(settings, successCallback, errorCallback);
};

MediaStreamTrack.getSources(devices);
```

This basically loops through all of the available devices and checks if it's a video source and that it is facing the user. It will then use the id of that device to create the media stream.